# Map custom properties when ingesting IoT hub into ADX

Tags: mapping, azure-iot-hub, azure-data-explorer

I have the following setup: an IoT Hub `ih1` routing messages to Azure Data Explorer `adx1`. Messages on the IoT hub look like the following:

```json
{
  "body": {
    { "value": "myValue" }
  },
  "messageId": "deadbeef-1234-5678-9abc-0123456789ab",
  "properties": {
    "myCustomProperty": "myCustomValue"
  }
}
```

(There are more root properties and more custom properties, but the above outline should be clear).

I want to map the **custom properties** of the IoT Hub message onto a table column. So far, I've only been able to map the [system properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct?WT.mc_id=Portal-fx#system-properties-of-d2c-iot-hub-messages) and the `body` property content (in above example: `"value": "myValue"`) to a column.

Using the `$.propertyName` will only refer to properties *within* the `body` property, not on properties on the root of the message.

How can I map custom properties to a column?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not implemented in ADX.
As a workaround you can route messages to en Event Hub and then to ADX. Then you should be able to access that properties.

Comment: Do you have a source for this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Payload enrichment for IoT Hubs and Event Hubs in ADX is currently not fully implemented and is limited to system properties only.
Full support is on the backlog but we have no ETA at the present time.

Comment: Do you have a source for this answer?

Comment: I manage the Data Ingestion team in ADX, so this is the best source you are going to get. When this functionality becomes available, it will be because my team will have implemented it.